# Webpack - trying to route/compile my CSS and JS files into CSS and JS specific sub-folders within dist/ folder

Tags: npm, webpack, css-loader, sass-loader, webpack.config.js

I'm pretty new to webpack in general.  Just a couple of days in really.  For the most part I feel like I've made some pretty good progress on at setting up and integrating webpack into my local development environment.  Quite a few bugs and command line errors along the way but I was able to work through most of them up to now.  Shout out to Maxmillian Schwärzmuller's short YT series on Webpack to get me started.

Now I'm trying to re-purpose/expand on some of the concepts I've picked up however I'm not yet having any success getting my `npm run build` (this would be the production command) to compile my CSS files into CSS and JS subfolders (off the root of the site) respectively.

I felt like I was making more progress with my attempts to use the `file-loader` package within my JS and CSS specific test blocks but now I'm wondering if I'm not either misunderstanding the purpose of the `file-loader` package or simply not configuring it correctly.

Here are the contents of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'styles.css'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['babel-preset-env']
            }
          }
          // attempted to replicate the same use statement as seen below for the jpg/png test
          // and only app.js (not app.bundle.js) was dropped into dist/js/
          // {
          //   loader: 'file-loader',
          //   options: {
          //     name: '[name].[ext]',
          //     outputPath: 'js/',
          //     publicPath: 'js/'

          //   }
          // }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
        // attempted to modify/replicate the above use statement
          // use: [
            // {
              // loader: 'css-loader',
              // loader: 'sass-loader'
              // loader: 'file-loader',
              // options: {
              //   name: '[name].[ext]',
              //   outputPath: 'css/',
              //   publicPath: 'css/'
              // }
            // }
          // ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
              publicPath: 'images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    extractPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
  ]
};
```

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
  {
  "name": "nodomaintoseehere.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Site repository v1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Jeremy Wilson",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

And finally the `app.js` file

```
import '../css/styles.scss';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: explain why the default behavior is does not fit your problem or what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: The default behavior is that the app.bundle.js and the styles.css file are being dumped into the root (dist) folder.  I don't want that.  I would like them diverted into their own /js and /css sub-directories respectively.  The code that is commented out in the webpack.config.js was unsuccessful in achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Putting assets into different subfolders does not make any differece in performance, nor in use since those are going to sit on your static server everytime until it is redeployed.

There is no way to output js files to js folder since there is no option on babel loader and file-loader does not handle  js, they just emit the file, in your case it would endup with duplicated files at the end. File-loader is not ideal to work with javascript files.

For css, you can configure extract-text-plugin.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'css/styles.css' // <---
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['babel-preset-env']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
              publicPath: 'images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    extractPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
  ]
};
```

Comment: Okay.  I understand.  The only real requirement I had for doing this was a that it mirrored the directory structure that I've used in the past and would simply have helped to organize my files.  I think your suggestion was bubbling up for me when I was typing this question out so I'm glad to see that I was close to another possible solution.  Thanks.

Comment: build files are pointless to work with, they are just meant to be compiled and left alone. It is better to worry with dev files, it is a better time wasted!